# How can I improve this code to object oriented programming?

Tags: java, oop

I would like improve this code to OOP in Java. How can I for example return value from variable avg or Can I put ArrayList in method parameters?

Thank you in advance

```
 class ArrayTester {
     private double sum;


     public void getAverageNotes() {


         List < Integer > theBigList = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
         Random theGenerator = new Random();
         for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

             theBigList.add(theGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1);
         }

         if (theBigList.size() > 2) {
             int max = Collections.max(theBigList);
             int min = Collections.min(theBigList);

             theBigList.remove(Integer.valueOf(max));
             theBigList.remove(Integer.valueOf(min));

             System.out.println(theBigList);
             for (int n = 0; n < theBigList.size(); n++) {
                 System.out.println("New note " + n + " of the Informatics is: " + theBigList.get(n));
                 sum = sum + theBigList.get(n);
             }
             System.out.println("Collection size is: " + theBigList.size() + "\nExtreme values are: " + min + " and " + max);
             double avg = Math.round(sum) / (double) theBigList.size();
             System.out.println("Average: " + String.format("%.2f", avg));

         } else {
             System.out.println("to small");
         }
```

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? Yes you can return the value of avg from the function by declaring the return type of the method to double instead of void . Also you can pass the ArrayList in the method paramters

Comment: could show me how can I do this?

Comment: [You already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63477344/3788176).

Comment: @Hayden in its current state, this question will be downvoted *and* closed on CodeReview (well, [it's already happening](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248121/how-can-i-rewrite-this-code-to-object-oriented-programming)). Please don't point users to CodeReview without further remarks. Also please never refer broken code to CodeReview, as broken code is strictly off-topic on CR.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the average by returning the avg once it has been calculated. If there are less than 2 items, it will return -1 as a result.

```
 public double getAverageNotes() {


        List<Integer> theBigList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random theGenerator = new Random();
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

            theBigList.add(theGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1);
        }
        
        if (theBigList.size() > 2) {
            double avg = 0;
            int max = Collections.max(theBigList);
            int min = Collections.min(theBigList);

            theBigList.remove(Integer.valueOf(max));
            theBigList.remove(Integer.valueOf(min));

            System.out.println(theBigList);
            int sum = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < theBigList.size(); n++) {
                System.out.println("New note " + n + " of the Informatics is: " + theBigList.get(n));
                sum = sum + theBigList.get(n);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Collection size is: " + theBigList.size() + "\nExtreme values are: " + min + " and " + max);
            avg = Math.round(sum) / (double) theBigList.size();
            System.out.println("Average: " + String.format("%.2f", avg));
            return avg;

        } else {
            System.out.println("to small");
            return -1;
        }


    }
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to put the ArrayList as a parameter, you can change the method signature:

```
public double getAverageNotes(List<Integer> list){
       
        List<Integer> theBigList = list;

       ...
```

and define the array list to be passed in:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random theGenerator = new Random();
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {

             list.add(theGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1);
         }
        System.out.println(getAverageNotes(list));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you everything is ok but i changed ArrayTester tester = new ArrayTester();
        tester.getAverageNotes(list); and now everything is display ok